# ¿Cómo comparar imágenes?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

Tengo un problema. Necesito obtener la imagen del `ImageView` y compararla con otra imagen que tengo en el `Drawable` y en caso de que sean iguales la guardo para usarla más adelante. El problema es que no logro compararlas de forma correcta. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Este es el código de lo que hice pero al ejecutarlo me dice que la aplicación se detuvo:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView iv1;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    public void b1(View view){

        int tagImageView = (int) iv1.getTag();
        if (tagImageView==R.drawable.imagen){
            Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(iv1.getResources(), R.drawable.imagen);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            String base64_imagen = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Guardar", base64_imagen);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Aleatorio para obtener imagen:

```
final Random rand = new Random();

            int arregloSeleccionado = rand.nextInt(100);

            if (arregloSeleccionado >= 0 && arregloSeleccionado <= 70) {
                final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.PlantasSimples);
                final Random rand2 = new Random();
                final int rndInt = rand2.nextInt(imgs.length());
                final int rID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
                planta.setImageResource(rID);                    

            } else if (arregloSeleccionado >= 71 && arregloSeleccionado <= 93) {
                final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.PlantasRaras);
                final Random rand2 = new Random();
                final int rndInt = rand2.nextInt(imgs.length());
                final int rID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
                planta.setImageResource(rID);                  

            } else if (arregloSeleccionado >= 94 && arregloSeleccionado <= 100) {
                final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.PlantaEspecial);
                final Random rand2 = new Random();
                final int rndInt = rand2.nextInt(imgs.length());
                final int rID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
                planta.setImageResource(rID);                    
            }              
        }
```

Comment: si te sirve un programa ya hecho aqui te envio el link, compara fotos y te indica el % de parecido en cada una de ellas. http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html

Answer (score 1):

Te falta 1 solo paso para verificar esto, a tu `ImageView` obtienes el `getTag` pero comparas luego con un resource, lo que debes hacer es crear un segundo `ImageView` con tu resource

```
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);  
image2.setTag(R.drawable.image);
if (iv1.getTag().equals(image2.getTag())) {
      //son iguales
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta eso funcionaria, el problema es que mi image view recibe una imagen aleatoria cuando se aprieta el botón y lo que quiero hacer es identificar esa imagen, ver cual de todas las imágenes que tengo en drawale es y guardarla para usarla después. Es posible hacer algo así? Gracias

Comment: Tienes codigo de como asignas ese valor de la imagen aleatorio?

Comment: Ultima pregunta, tu variable PLANTA es el imageview que cargas y verificas despues?

Comment: Si, disculpa me olvide de cambiarle el nombre, "planta" es el image view que recibe la imagen aleatoria y que después quiero ver que imagen recibió para comparar

Comment: Este codigo es clave para saber que imagen se le dio imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0); guarda ese valor y asi sabras que imagen se le entrego

Answer (score 0):

El código para ésto será algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
//Obtener todos los pixeles de la imagen 1
int w1 = bufferedImage1.getWidth(null);
int h1 = bufferedImage1.getHeight(null);
int[] rgbs1 = new int[w1*h1];
bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0, w1, h1, rgbs1, 0, w1);

//De forma similar para la imagen 2
...
```

Luego de haber creado los dos arreglos de pixeles utiliza el método equals para compararlos:

```
if(rgbs1.equals(rgbs2))
    System.out.println("Son iguales");
else
    System.out.println("Son diferentes");
```

Con este código comparamos las imágenes pixel a pixel

Respuesta sacada de https://www.todoexpertos.com/categorias/tecnologia-e-internet/programacion/java/respuestas/1217934/comparar-imagenes-jpg-en-java